# Rest assured test failed with error "at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach"

Tags: java, groovy, rest, rest-assured

Every time I want to run my test it returns me an error in line that contains RestAssured.given()

I tried different code examples from every where and every time it returns the same error in the same line that contains RestAssured.given()

this is my code

```
    package com.restassured.testcases;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers;
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class Test01_GET {
    @Test
    public static void test01(){
    RestAssured.given().when().get("http://google.com").then().statusCode(200);

    }
}
```

---

and this is the error returned

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/C:/Users/mmaksoud/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.8/groovy-2.5.8.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.<init>(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:147)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.createTestSpecification(RestAssured.java:1452)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.given(RestAssured.java:653)
    at com.restassured.testcases.Test01_GET.test01(Test01_GET.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Comment: Coud you add java version and version of your dependencies in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using an older version of `rest-assured` (4.2.0?) which has a dependency on an older version of Groovy (2.5.8) which is not compatible with your JVM version.

To fix this, try upgrading `rest-assured` to a later version (4.4.0 is the most recent at the time of writing) which is bundled with Groovy 3.0.8, which is a more recent version, and should fix the issue you're currently facing.